# c# asp net how to set enabled and visible properties of elements using code behind according to user permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, getelementsbytagname

I'm using C# ASP NET to make a web page.
I Need to set properties Enabled and Visible for elements in HTML pages according to the user permission.
It includes NavBar (menu), Buttons, charts, everything...

I will bring the information from a database. I believe i will need this information in database:
1- Screen (String) 
2- Name of element (string)
3- Visible (bool)
4- Enabled

Can I have an unique function to change all this properties in OnLoadPage / OnInit?
Does exists something like "getElementByName()" that brings any kind of elements to easily change its properties (Visible / Enabled)?

I found some problems because I'm using also DevExpress and I couldn't use just FindControl() to find all elements in a dx:aspnetGridView for example.

Examples:

```
public class ElementData
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }


    public void Adiciona(string Path, bool Visible, bool Enabled)
    {
        this.Path = Path;
        this.Visible = Visible;
        this.Enabled = Enabled;
    }
}

public class UserMembershipElementsData
{
    //User
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    //Membership
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; } 

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public List<ElementData> ElementsList { get; set; }

    public UserMembershipElementsData(string Nome, string UserName, string Password, string Email)
    {
        this.UserName = UserName;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.Nome = Nome;
        this.Email = Email;

        this.ElementsList = new List<ElementData>();
    }
}



    public UserMembershipElementsData usr = new UserMembershipElementsData("Joao","admin","pass","jairo@tnah.com.br"); //declared as public

   ElementData elm = new ElementData(); //just part of the code
   elm.Adiciona("btnAdiciona", true, false); //Add, Visible, Disabled
   usr.ElementsList.Add(elm);

protected void grdDados_CustomButtonInitialize(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.VisibleIndex == -1) return;
        foreach (ElementData elm in usr.ElementsList)
        {
            if (e.ButtonID == elm.Path)
            {
                e.Visible = DefaultBoolean.True; ///Permission I couldnt use elm.Visible    
                e.Enabled = elm.Enabled; //Permission
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I'm just testing, I didn't put the name of the page yeat.
I would be happy if you give me a way to follow. Thanks.

Comment: I tryied using DataBinding but the problem is that dx:asp GridView doesn't permit DataBinding.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is at the begining of the page I declare a variable.
lets say:

`@var canUserSee = UserMembershipElementsData.HasAdminRole();
   //then razor
   @if(canUserSee)
    <button id="ButtonAdmin">Just Admins can see this button</button>`

Note: this is based on Roles permissions and you have to implement the function HasAdminRole(). Also you can implement functions for specific controls for example  bool HasUserRightToControl (ElementData control ).